# Javadoc-like wrapping for Enum descriptions

Tags: android

When I have the following class in Android Studio:

```
public enum RelationshipType {
    BORING,
    LOVE_HATE,
    LOVE,
    HATE
}
```

And start to annotate the important enum constants:

```
public enum RelationshipType {
    /**
     * Fallback for all other relationships.
     */
    BORING,
    /**
      * Ah, most interesting one!
      */
    LOVE_HATE,
    LOVE,
    HATE
}
```

Android Studio Code Formatting makes this out of it:

```
public enum RelationshipType {
    /**
     * Fallback for all other relationships.
     */
    BORING, /**
      * Ah, most interesting one!
      */
    LOVE_HATE, LOVE, HATE
}
```

I am fine with `LOVE_HATE`, `LOVE` and `HATE` being in the same line, but I really dislike that `/**` is getting pulled up after `BORING,`.

In the code formatting settings, there is a *Wrapping and Braces* > *Enum constants* options, giving the following options:

- Do not wrap – same problem.
- Wrap if long – same problem.
- Chop down if long – same problem.
- Wrap always – solves this problem, but prevents single-line enum definitions.

I could not find an option like *Wrap always before javadoc comments*. Is there one anywhere?